# Does SQL Server 2012 have a function or other way to convert a varchar column that contains ASCII to plain text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've inherited a database table that has an nvarchar(MAX) column containing ASCII numbers.  I need to convert and replace them with plain text.  Is this possible using an SQL function?

From:

> 034 067 111 110 118 101 114 116 032 077 101 044 032 068 097 114 110 032 105 116 033 033 034

To:

> "Convert Me, Darn it!!"

Thanks all

Comment: Have you googled SQL STRING FUNCTIONS?

Comment: The [CHAR()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) function converts a single ASCII number to a character, but you'd need to split the string into tokens and convert each one.

Comment: My condolences. Any idea why ASCII codes were saved in a Unicode column instead of the text itself? Anyway, the `CHAR` function will return the character corresponding to an ASCII character, but you need to split the string first

Comment: Thanks stuart and panagiotis, that works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ASCII_Col VARCHAR(1000))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('034 067 111 110 118 101 114 116 032 077 101 044 032 068 097 114 110 032 105 116 033 033 034')
```

### Query

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT CHAR(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) Char_Vals
FROM   (SELECT 
              Cast ('<M>' + Replace(ASCII_Col, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   @Table) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) 
   )
SELECT (SELECT  '' + Char_Vals
         FROM CTE
         FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
```

### Result

```
"Convert Me, Darn it!!"
```

Comment: Appreciate the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

A solution (without `split` function):

```
declare @input nvarchar(max);
declare @result nvarchar(max);

select @result = '';
select @input = '034 067 111 110 118 101 114 116 032 077 101 044 032 068 097 114 110 032 105 116 033 033 034';
--------------------------------
declare @index int;
declare @len int;
declare @char char(1);
declare @charNum varchar(8);

set @charNum = '';
set @index = 1;
set @len= LEN(@input);

WHILE @index <= @len + 1
BEGIN
    set @char = SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1);
    if (@char = ' ') begin
        set @result = @result + char(@charNum);
        set @charNum = '';
    end else begin
        set @charNum = @charNum + @char;
    end;

    set @index = @index + 1;
END

select @result as [Output];
```

..and the result is:

```
OUTPUT:
----------------------
"Convert Me, Darn it!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to skin the cat:

```
SELECT CAST(x AS nvarchar(max))
FROM @TABLE
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP(1+LEN(ASCII_Col)/4)
    CHAR(SUBSTRING(ASCII_Col,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))*4-3,3))
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values
  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
) t(x)
```